# how to select boot mode if key is not working

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My cellphone is not opening. It creat a lot problem. When I press switch on button.
It gives on plain light and switch off again. When I press switch and volume up key than it opened and written on screen that select boot mode use up volume key to select recovery mode or normal boot or fast boot and to select use down volume key.

Comment: If your phone has a removable battery, try removing it and place it and switch it on by long pressing the power button for around 20 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Is your phone rooted?
if not search "your phone model  + root" in google.

If it is rooted then try to download an app called quickboot and see if that helps.

otherwise send it to customer care.

Comment: Your answer is not helpful. 1) It doesn't matter whether the phone is rooted or not since OP can't even boot to Android OS. 2) Always link the app you're suggesting. 3) Almost everyone knows to do that as the last resort. // The real question is how to boot into Android OS since the normal way doesn't make it boot and the other way requires using a key which isn't working.  Please read  [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Firelord Well OP did not specify his question clearly so i could not understand what was actually wrong with his phone.

Comment: And btw quickboot is pretty searchable on google.

Comment: OP's phone is possible soft bricked as implied by his first sentence in which case a firmware flash will be required.

Comment: OP also did not provide his phone model which makes it difficult to answer his question.  Perhaps you should suggest OP to read How to Write a Good question?.

Comment: BTW everything is pretty much searchable on the Google or whatsoever but that's not the point. If you don't understand the question clearly then  **please do not post the answers**. Instead, seek clarification using comments or leave it for the others and then post the answer based on OP's feedback. You would need 50 reputation points or more to comment anywhere. As I linked earlier which I believe you didn't read, note "*[Write to the best of your ability](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)*". Thanks. Please keep up the good work of answering though.

Comment: Look i did made a mistake. i am admitting it. but if people keep repeatedly posting vague questions like this how can we help them?.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. The thing is, there is a structure here. I'll explain briefly: Not everyone posts such vague question but unfortunately we do receive a lot of such questions. In order to improve them you can [edit them](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing) (but don't change the intent). If you need clarification because you think you can answer there, you can comment. You would need 50 reputation points to comment anywhere. Issue is, *how would you get those 50 points if you can't answer vague questions*? Well, an approved edit to a post would give you 2 points.

Comment: A vote to a question asked by you would give you 5 points. A vote to a good answer posted to an *unanswered* but good *and old question* would give you 10 points. You can do the maths. [There are many good questions waiting to be answered](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). Just search them and answer them. But please follow the [answer guidelines](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) when you do that. Good luck!